# Javascript Canvas imperfect pixels using drawImage and imageSmoothing disabled

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I have disabled image smoothing using

```
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

If you look at the orange object in the image below (zoomed in with chrome)
you can see how the pixels are weirdly aligned.

[image: weird pixels]

I can assure you that the original image is an 8x8 with perfectly placed pixels:

[image: original image]

I'm not sure if this is a result of disabling image smoothing or if it's got to do with the resolution of the canvas. How do I make the pixels consistent and regularly sized?

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/khjnqLjo/1/

Comment: Could you include a live example? I can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/khjnqLjo/

Comment: @Kaiido change: ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0, 80, 80); to ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0, 20, 20);

Comment: Ah. Then it's because the ratio 20/8 is 2.5, so the closest-neighbor algo will mangle one pixel where this half precision occurs. Here is a better quality result: https://jsfiddle.net/khjnqLjo/2/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks but how do I fix that so that the scaled image looks the same as the provided example where every pixel looks the same?

Comment: Well scale your image by an integer ratio. Setting your scaled image size  to `16` or `24` will do. https://jsfiddle.net/khjnqLjo/4/

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you so much! Sorry for not understanding basic image manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing an image of 8x8 pixels to a 20x20 rectangle. This will lead to incorrect scaling because you can't draw half pixels. Solve this by setting your rectangle size to a multiple of eight or change your original image to be 10 pixels in width/height.